# Updating ObjectName of widget does not not update the style automatically

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

In my application, the stylesheet for the entire application is taken from a resource file loaded into the application.

I have two stylesheets defined there for a QListWidget:

```
QListWidget#Good{
..some color properties
}

QListWidget#Bad {
..soem different color properties
}
```

In a form, my QListWidget's Object name is "Good", so it adheres to the #good style. During runtime, I have a case where I want to "SetObjectName" it to "Bad" and have the style changed instantly in the UI.

I have noticed two things:

1. merely calling "SetObjectName("Bad");" doens't change the style from methods...
2. The only time "SetObjectName("Bad");" works is if called from the constructor of the Widget containing the QListWidget.

Obviously i am missing some "update style" phase. Note that I cannot have "setStyleSheet" in code, it must come from the QSS file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got this resolved. Calling:

```
style()->unpolish(theWidget);
style()->polish(theWidget);
```

On my widget after the change of objectName (`setObjectName`) did the trick.